# Mobile devices touch event with css

Tags: javascript, css

I have made a simple card system with mobile.

When I use below code, touch event detect very well.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.card1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
.card1:active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body ontouchstart="">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="card1"></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Not only in mobile devices but also works fine in the desktop.

But after detach the finger from the screen, it return to original state.

My goal is if I click touch the box, box will be changed to `background-color: blue;` and do not have to return `background-color: green;`

Is there any solution here?

Thanks.

Comment: try onclick instead of ontouchstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by applying background color on click event using js

```js
$('.card1').click(function() {
    $('.card1').css({
        'background-color': 'blue',        
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.card1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body ontouchstart="">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="card1"></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```